# Is it possible in PHP to determine if a preg pattern is valid

Tags: php

preg_match() will return

```
preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash
```

if the pattern is not well-formed. Is there a function to determine (TRUE or FALSE) if the pattern is well-formed *before* passing it preg_match()?

Comment: Try reading documentation > http://php.net/manual/bg/function.preg-match.php  if there is error it will return False.

Answer (score 0):

```
$match = preg_match('regex', 'string');

if ($match === false) {
    // failed
} elseif ($match == false) {
    // did not matched
} else {
    // matched
}
```